# MongoDB Aggregation Project Stage access element of _id

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to rollup data by time segments for various document elements.  I need to present the timestamp for the time segment in the output document, but am having trouble extracting it from the id element.  My code is:

```
var baseDate = new Date(2017, 01, 11, 00, 00, 0);
var startDate = new Date(2017, 01, 11, 00, 00, 0);
var endDate = new Date(2018, 09, 20, 14, 25, 0);
var divisor = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 minutes in miliseconds

db.AUDIT.aggregate([ 
    {
        $match : {
            requestDtsCal : {
                $gte : startDate,
                $lt : endDate
            }
        }
    }, {
        $group : {
            _id : { timestamp: {
                    $subtract : [ "$requestDtsCal", {
                        $mod : [ {
                            $subtract : [ "$requestDtsCal", baseDate ]
                        }, divisor ]
                    } ]
                }, 
                serviceKey: "$serviceKey",
                contractKey: "$contractKey",
                bindingTemplateKey: "$bindingTemplateKey",
                containerKey: "$containerKey"
            },
            count: {$sum: 1},
            contract: 
                {$first: { name: "$contractName", id: "$contractId", key: "$contractKey"}}
        }
    }, { $project: { 
            _id: 1,
            contract: 1,
            count: 1
        } 
    }
]).pretty();
```

The output of this is a series of these objects:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-17T06:00:00Z"),
        "serviceKey" : "uddi:soa.com:ws-mex-servicekey",
        "contractKey" : "d36ac6d6-7473-11e6-8466-ba5d36e9bcc7:1001",
        "bindingTemplateKey" : "uddi:d6e13584-7655-11e6-8911-aed52c780d1b",
        "containerKey" : "acb7eb7f-b28e-4ead-944f-ed116d61"
    },
    "count" : 30,
    "contract" : {
        "name" : null,
        "id" : 1001,
        "key" : "d36ac6d6-7473-11e6-8466-ba5d36e9bcc7:1001"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-17T06:10:00Z"),
        "serviceKey" : "uddi:soa.com:ws-mex-servicekey",
        "contractKey" : "d36ac6d6-7473-11e6-8466-ba5d36e9bcc7:1001",
        "bindingTemplateKey" : "uddi:d6e13584-7655-11e6-8911-aed52c780d1b",
        "containerKey" : "acb7eb7f-b28e-4ead-944f-ed116d61"
    },
    "count" : 30,
    "contract" : {
        "name" : null,
        "id" : 1001,
        "key" : "d36ac6d6-7473-11e6-8466-ba5d36e9bcc7:1001"
    }
}
```

I don't want to output the whole _id element, just the timestamp, but I can't seem to make this work.  I tried adding `_id.timestamp` to the project element, but this doesn't seem to be valid.  This is with Mongo 3.2.11 FYI.

Any tips on how to best generate an output element that contains the timestamp without including the _id?

Update.  Per comments, I tried:

```
{ $project: { 
    "_id.timestamp": 1,
    contract: 1,
    count: 1
}
```

This does result in output with only the timestamp, but it's wrapped in the _id outer element:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "timestamp" : "2018-01-17 05:20:00.000Z"
    },
    "count" : 32,
    "contract" : {
        "name" : null,
        "id" : 1001,
        "key" : "d36ac6d6-7473-11e6-8466-ba5d36e9bcc7:1001"
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: Try `{
   $project:{
      _id:0, timestamp:"$_id.timestamp",
      contract:1,
      count:1
   }
}`

Comment: This returns the _id outer element with only the timestamp in it, so that's good.  The issue is that I don't want that outer element, I only want the _timestamp.

Comment: Not sure I follow you it returns only timestamp so no id (_id :0 to exclude id ). There is no outer element.

Comment: See edit to original question for the result.  Hard to paste it in a comment.

Comment: No, Try `{ $project:{ _id:0, timestamp:"$_id.timestamp", contract:1, count:1 }`. See I've included `_id:0`

Comment: That gives the same result.  Selecting only an inner element of the _id turns off all the other elements automatically, but even with _id:0 it still returns the wrapping element for "_id.timestamp".

Comment: Still not sure. So I did this `db.col.insert({
    "_id" : {
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-17T06:10:00Z"),
        "serviceKey" : "uddi:soa.com:ws-mex-servicekey",
        "contractKey" : "d36ac6d6-7473-11e6-8466-ba5d36e9bcc7:1001",
        "bindingTemplateKey" : "uddi:d6e13584-7655-11e6-8911-aed52c780d1b",
        "containerKey" : "acb7eb7f-b28e-4ead-944f-ed116d61"
    },
    "count" : 30,
    "contract" : {
        "name" : null,
        "id" : 1001,
        "key" : "d36ac6d6-7473-11e6-8466-ba5d36e9bcc7:1001"
    }
})` and  ran

Comment: `db.col.aggregate({ $project:{ _id:0, timestamp:"$_id.timestamp", contract:1, count:1 }});` and got `{ "count" : 30, "contract" : { "name" : null, "id" : 1001, "key" : "d36ac6d6-7473-11e6-8466-ba5d36e9bcc7:1001" }, "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-17T06:10:00Z") }` as response. What am i missing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163501/discussion-between-iang-and-veeram).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below project stages which excludes the existing _id and maps the timestamp field from _id into its own field.

Something like

```
{ $project:{ _id:0, timestamp:"$_id.timestamp", contract:1, count:1 }}
```

Comment: Great answer, and also thanks so much for the help in char.